# How can I take the transpose for a DataArray with repeated dimensions?

Tags: python-xarray

Suppose I have a `DataArray` with dimensions `(a, b, b)`:

```
In [111]: da = xarray.DataArray(arange(2*5*5).reshape(2, 5, 5), dims=("a", "b", "b"))
```

How can I take the transpose, swapping the order of the final two dimensions?

```
In [112]: da.T
```

results in

```
ValueError: repeated axis in transpose
```

As does `da.transpose("a", "b", "b")`.

My data arrays contain covariance matrices, so it is natural that the final dimension is repeated.

Comment: Just as a warning, using repeated dimensions in xarray is probably going to be fairly buggy. There is an open Github issue on the subject: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1378

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
db = xarray.DataArray(da.values.T, dims=("a", "b", "b"))
```

thus bypassing xarray.  Experimentation shows that `db` is still a view of the same memory as `da`, which in my case is entirely desirable.